# Right Click and Hit the Tab Button

Tags: edit-mode

I'm new to blender. I'm trying to right click on the image to change the text but no cursor is showing to allow me to backspace.I have watched YouTube videos and the make it look simple. They all say right click and hit the tab.
 What and where is tab?
How do I make the cursor appear?

Comment: The tab button on your keyboard? It's until the ~

Answer (score 1):

Right-clicking selects the object you want to edit (in this case, it would be your text), and the "tab" button on your keyboard (above caps lock) allows you to enter into Edit Mode. Alternatively, you could right-click on your text and then enter Edit Mode via the menu at the bottom of your screen where it says "Object Mode".

Check out this link and see if it helps: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/texts/editing.html